# Using @Value annotation with Spring and SPeL

Tags: spring

I am trying to find a way to do the following in my spring boot 1.5 application.

1. I have a variable who's value is dynamic meaning it comes in from an external system.

   `String name = "abc"; //gets set externally`
2. I want to try and use the name's value to lookup my property file and see if there is a matching property defined. something like..

   `@Value("#{myClassName.name.concat('something')}")
   String propertyValue;`

Now my application.property file has the following property set
assume name has the value "abc"

### property file contents:

```
abc.something:abcValue
```

Now, when i try to access the value of the variable `propertyValue` it gets set to the value `abc.something` and not `abcValue`.

I probably think I cannot use `@Value` with `#{}` to get to that, I was wondering if there was a way to to use `#{}` inside `${}` so that I goes and fetches the property value after calculating the name of the property using `#{}`.

Let me know if you need more details please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bean life-cycle requires properties to be resolved at compile time. So, `@Value` requires constant parameter.

[image]

You can use `Environment` bean to access your properties programmatically.

```
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@Service
public class Serivce {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    public String getProperty(final String keyPart) {
        String key = "build.your." + keyPart;
        return environment.getProperty(key)
    }
}
```

By the way you can use `#('${spring.some.property}')` in SpEL to access placeholder.

```
// This is valid access to property
@Value("#('${spring.some.property}')")
private String property;
```