# How to use @Value inject a value to Dao?

Tags: spring, annotations, mybatis

I want to make the name of databse configurable. I put the database'name in config.properties, and try to get it through @Value in a Dao. But it doesn't work.

Is it possible to inject value to Dao through @Value?

```
@Repository
public interface PageReportDao {

    @Value("${database.name}")
    String DATABASE = "0";

    /**
     * 获取页面最大面板
     * @param pageId
     * @return
     */
    @Select("SELECT page_id FROM " + DATABASE + ".table WHERE page_id=#{page_id}")
    String getPageInfo(@Param("page_id") int pageId);
}
```

Comment: Is the PageReportDao object being created by Spring? If so, beyond a typo or being in a properties file not being loaded, it should be injected. The property name has a typo as it is written here ```databse.name```. As well config.properties is not the default property file Spring loads (it's application.properties), I guess is loaded explicitly. As a side comment, if you switch to use spring-data this would be much simpler.

Comment: Maybe helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45020151/using-value-annotation-with-spring-and-spel/45020691#45020691

Comment: @PedroR. The typo exits both in config file and this Dao, so it doesn't matter. PageReportDao is created by Spring, but it's a interface, and "String DATABASE" is not a field of it, it's just a constant, is it possible to inject a value to a constant?

Comment: @J-Alex   Thank you. But i can inject value in a Service file, but can't do it in this interface. I'm wondering is it possible to do injection in interface.

Comment: True, sorry, being that field final it cannot get that value.

Answer (score 1):

You can't inject the value like this. First of all every field in interface is implicitly final so this would not even compile

Even if you could inject the value, the argument to `@Select` should be a constant expression so this would not work.

There's however a way to achieve what you want by using global parameter. You first define the parameter in your `SqlSessionFactory`:

```
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="configurationProperties">
    <props>
      <prop key="database">${database.name}</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
</bean>
```

And then use it in a mapper:

```
 @Repository
 public interface PageReportDao {

    @Select("SELECT page_id FROM ${database}.table WHERE page_id=#{page_id}")
    String getPageInfo(@Param("page_id") int pageId);
}
```

In this case mybatis itself will expand that variable.